# how do you pronounce "to" in American Accent in this sentence

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

I have this sentence

> I have come here to chew ... etc

I know that the **to** in that sentence is pronounced as **da** in American accent.

my question is, is the **to** is also pronounce as **da** in this sentence

> I have come here to study ... etc

Comment: It is not pronounced as "da" in most American accents. The syllable would be spoken close to "ti" and the phrase *t' study* in my section of the country, the northeast.

Comment: @TRomano i am following this small video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fp11y7wUh2k and the lecturer states that the **to** is pronounced as **da**, now i am confused after your comment

Comment: The guy in the glasses doesn't say "da". He says "tu:" (rhymes with "food" and "blue"), and he is pronouncing the word more fully and articulately than most speakers do when they're speaking at a normal rate.

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/6.mitx/www/24.900%20IPA/IPAapp.html

Comment: It sounds like 'da' to my ear too [Br E]. heerdachoo… @5.30 Not when he over pronounces, bu when he forgets & speaks at full speed. My theory is always that most US speakers don't hear it as that in normal conversation, but to my ear t is very very often softened to d

Comment: @TRomano no she said **da**, I copied the video with the second when he said **da** listen please https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fp11y7wUh2k&t=173 and give you kindly opinion

Comment: @TRomano what is that website you gave me please? it sounds interesting, but i couldn't know how to work with it

Comment: @Tetsujin so are you suggesting that I use **da** when I say **to study** ?

Comment: I've listened to almost 2 minutes worth and he said "to" maybe 8 or 9 times and always it was pronounced `tu:`. Please identify the time-marker where you're hearing `da`

Comment: @TRomano when he was teaching us the correct spelling of **to** , he said **da** at about 1:58 [timestamped link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fp11y7wUh2k&t=1m58s)

Comment: If you're going to copy the YouTube guy's speed & diction, I'd say yes - but I'm not American, so the subtle distinction between what an American hears as 'to' & what I hear as 'da' would probably be to small for either of us to really know we got it right.

Comment: @TRomano & 10s later he repeats 'heerda' twice just so we get it

Comment: I think for this type of thing, the major US/UK difference is US elides to 'd' whereas UK would glottal stop & lose the 't' altogether

Comment: Listen to him when he's speaking normally, not when he's exaggerating for your supposed benefit.

Comment: I waded through the next few minutes of it - he not only does say 'da', he goes on to explain why. The prosecution rests, milord ;)

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and say that eliding the 'to' with the previous word (hereduh chew) is typical of a kind of rough street talk (*I'm hereduh kick your ass, muthafucka*) whereas connecting 'to' to the bare infinitive is typical of a more normal register (*I'm here t'see Mr Jones about a summer internship*). I think the ESL teacher is  getting into playing the role of the person in the movie.

Comment: very possibly, it ain't Harvard ;)

Comment: @Marco - I'd suggest you find some old episodes of Frasier & spot the difference in how the main characters speak compared to this example. They use a 'highly-educated' form of American {I don't know the equivalent US term for Received Pronunciation]. `Frasier` is a US TV comedy show [very funny actually] - it ran for years & there's a lot of it on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=frasier). The rest of my sentence was '[spot the difference](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=definition+%22spot+the+difference%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)' between the accents

Comment: @TRomano yes I got u, and I too find it as a street pronunciation  :)

Comment: In American films and TV, a stereotypical way to indicate that the speaker is somewhere on the oafish continuum is to de-dentalize:  t becomes d; d becomes a very muddy d with far too much tongue pressed up against the roof of the mouth, and even that muddy d can be further de-dentalized with a slack jaw.

Comment: You really need to reword this question, I think. Saying, _"I know that the_ **to** _in that sentence is pronounced as_ **da** _in American accent"_ is going to confuse a LOT of people – particularly Americans. It would be better to say something like: "The _to_ in that sentence can be pronounced as _da_ **in certain situations**." And please don't be in such a [hurry to accept an answer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: @J.R. if you want to edit my question, do whatever you want, but for me, i see the question is clear 100%

Comment: Here is what I heard (when he pronounced *to* consciously and unconsciously), 0:12 "listen *t'*", 0:19 "*to* chew bubblegum", 0:46 "*to* chew bubblegum", 1:15 "*to* chew bubblegum", 1:23 "*to* chew bubblegum", 1:33 "*to* chew bubblegum", 1:37 "*to* chew bubblegum", 1:54 "*to* kill the aliens", 1:59 "*d'* chew bubblegum", 2:07 "come here *dah*, come here *dah*", 2:17 "*to, tah, tuh, t', dah, duh, d'*", 2:40 "here *to*, here *to*", 2:54 "here d', here d'" ... Then I got lazy and stopped. :-)

Comment: @Marco - I didn't say it was unclear; I only meant to say that it seems to be based on a faulty premise – at least at first read.

Comment: Be careful trusting the comments on this question—they're full of errors and can't be downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

As a native American Speaker, hopefully I can clarify a little bit. The first thing you need to understand is American Accents vary a lot, with the biggest factors being location, class and to a lesser extent race.

With location, I'd say their are 3-4 different accents, and the a couple of city-specific accents. There is a southern accent (has a distinctive drawl, more likely to say words like "ya'll" [you-all]), mid-west (which I don't think I could explain, as this is my accent), east-coast (sounds a little bit more formal to my ear) and big city (sounds very rushed and hurried). Some city specific accents are "The Brooklyn Accent" (The main character or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgFwhj4hMSg) TV show has a great example of the stereotypical Brooklyn accent, which has a strong connotation with The Mafia) and "The Boston Accent" (There is a joke that if you say "I lost my khakis" it means you are lost your pants, but if you say it in Boston, it means you lost your "Car keys").

The other big distinction in American Accent is formality and class. An upper-class American is more likely to speak formally all the time, a middle-class American will occasionally speak formally, and occasionally informally, and a lower-class American will speak informally most if not all of the time. When speaking informally, "to" often becomes fused with the previous word.

> Do you *want to* build a snowman?

becomes

> Do you **wanna** build a snowman?

> Are you *going to* get me my money?

becomes

> Are you **gonna** get me my money?

Although keep in mind, you would never ever hear someone say

> I'm *gonna* the store.

even in very informal speech, although you could hear

> I'm **gonna** *go to* the store.

This "To" contraction only works with certain words, like going and want. I can't think of any other words this works with right now.

To will frequently be pronounced "duh" when the speaker is "Thuggish", lower-class, or from the south. (That last sentence sounds like I'm poking fun at people from the south, that was not my point. I have no animosity towards those from the south.)

> I'll go out on a limb and say that eliding the 'to' with the previous word (hereduh chew) is typical of a kind of rough street talk (I'm hereduh kick your ass, muthafucka) whereas connecting 'to' to the bare infinitive is typical of a more normal register (I'm here t'see Mr Jones about a summer internship). I think the ESL teacher is getting into playing the role of the person in the movie. - TRomano
>
> In American films and TV, a stereotypical way to indicate that the speaker is somewhere on the oafish continuum is to de-dentalize: t becomes d; d becomes a very muddy d with far too much tongue pressed up against the roof of the mouth, and even that muddy d can be further de-dentalized with a slack jaw. – TRomano

I agree with @TRomano here, but I have two little thoughts. First, I think that with a rough street talk, the "th" in `"muthaf*cka"` would be a 'd' sound, so `"I'm hereda kick your ass muddaf*cka!"` is a more likely pronunciation.

Second, I disagree with what he said about how to pronounce "I'm here t'see Mr Jones about a summer internship". This is likely a difference in location (TRomano said he is from the northeast, whereas I am from the midwest) and formality. I have noticed that east-coast tends to sound more educated and formal. If I were to say this sentence in real life, I would say "I'm here to (too) see Mr Jones about a summer internship."

Comment: Midwestern is somewhat nasal, and tends to emphasize certain vowels.

Comment: Also, the Boston accent joke I've heard was the woman who kept asking if her companion had "PSDS". It took some time for the companion to realize she was asking if she had pierced ears.